How to generate Zero values in a gap
I have some data where there is simply a gap in the data and I need those gaps to be value '0'. Given the data below, thing 'a', 'b' and 'c' would ideally have +/- 12 hours of data around a given period. Where no data exists, that should be a 0
select *
from (
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 12:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 13:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 14:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 15:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 16:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 17:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 18:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 19:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 21:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 22:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 23:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 15:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 16:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 17:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 18:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 19:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'c' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 12:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual
) where t between  timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' - interval '12' hour
    and  timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' + interval  '12' hour

I know this is possible, but I am not quite sure how.

This can be solved by generating all of the combinations of things and hours that you are interested in and then LEFT OUTER JOINING that generated data to your actual table.
In your example it would look like:
WITH input_data AS 
(
  select *
  from (
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 12:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 13:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 14:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 15:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 16:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 17:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 18:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 19:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 21:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 22:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 23:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 15:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 16:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 17:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 18:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 19:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'b' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    select 'c' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 12:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual
  ) 
)
,hours AS 
(
  select timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' + numtodsinterval(rownum,'HOUR') as hr
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
,things AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT thing FROM input_data
)
/*cross join to generate all the data you are wanting*/
, hourthings AS
(
  SELECT hr, thing
  FROM hours 
     CROSS JOIN things
)
/*now join it all together*/
SELECT 
  hourthings.thing,
  hourthings.hr,
  COALESCE(input_data.v, 0) as v
FROM hourthings
  LEFT OUTER JOIN input_data
     ON hourthings.thing = input_data.thing
     AND hourthings.hr = input_data.t
ORDER BY thing, hr, v;


+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| THING |              HR              |                    V                    |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| a     | 19-DEC-24 12.00.00.000000000 | .69774073052016968823672302782349609322 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 13.00.00.000000000 | .74681895242556208805921962750792112372 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 14.00.00.000000000 | .13895201336452094187697669624078005226 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 15.00.00.000000000 | .45337500667932949332016060056416492918 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 16.00.00.000000000 | .18899747383037346346775198378542334477 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 17.00.00.000000000 | .67102219547677447329531648462053776372 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 18.00.00.000000000 | .66857093410415223366767066184514813993 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 19.00.00.000000000 | .40391951442247044543080670749491385357 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 20.00.00.000000000 | .66678394623467745293923962502423558974 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 21.00.00.000000000 | .08192799627659883827769961887128183705 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 22.00.00.000000000 | .82864536740652777939535875967936388967 |
| a     | 19-DEC-24 23.00.00.000000000 | .06074762180454381335128190562038752096 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 12.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 13.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 14.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 15.00.00.000000000 | .49068229240906850444551902753208786223 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 16.00.00.000000000 | .49309406570981735526120776844366484152 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 17.00.00.000000000 | .81504764682984037766335094773881648938 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 18.00.00.000000000 | .56003821415269263216558677201167824597 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 19.00.00.000000000 | .47232889342064636947176597827340419611 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 20.00.00.000000000 | .26243408497186222403849841769849597216 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 21.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 22.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| b     | 19-DEC-24 23.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 12.00.00.000000000 | .82675839474283690631176461696378570193 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 13.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 14.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 15.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 16.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 17.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 18.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 19.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 20.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 21.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 22.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
| c     | 19-DEC-24 23.00.00.000000000 |                                       0 |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+

A working example of this can be found at this dbfiddle
That SQL is more verbose than necessary as the three last CTEs could be collapsed into a single statement, but this more verbose write-up will help for understanding each logical step.

Very (very) similar to @Jnevill's approach, but generating the +/-12 hours from your range (so 16 hours/rows per thing), and restricting to only things that have any relevant data (on the assumption, that may well be wrong, that if your data has a thing 'd' which only has data from a week ago you don't want to see 16 zeros for that).
-- CTE data replaces your subquery; presumably really a table
with data as (
    select 'a' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual union all
    ...
    select 'c' as thing, timestamp '2024-12-19 12:00:00' as t, DBMS_RANDOM.value() as v from dual
),
-- recursive CTE r to generate all the timestanps
r (t, range_end) as (
    select timestamp '2024-12-19 20:00:00' - interval '12' hour,
           timestamp '2024-12-19 11:00:00' + interval '12' hour
    from dual
    union all
    select r.t + interval '1' hour, r.range_end
    from r
    where r.t < r.range_end
),
-- CTE t to get all the 'thing' values with any t in the range
t (thing) as (
  select distinct d.thing
  from r
  join data d on d.t = r.t
)
select t.thing, r.t, coalesce(d.v, 0) as v
from r
cross join t
left join data d on d.thing = t.thing and d.t = r.t
order by thing, t




THING
T
V




a
2024-12-19 08:00:00
0


a
2024-12-19 09:00:00
0


a
2024-12-19 10:00:00
0


a
2024-12-19 11:00:00
.81925220362061454449360115427045870169


a
2024-12-19 12:00:00
.32486207409523001624110325935965313093


a
2024-12-19 13:00:00
.19957744192765894299446012947199614254


a
2024-12-19 14:00:00
.34510589960752126880971014998502503837


a
2024-12-19 15:00:00
.29039446043409292290338470624645241641


a
2024-12-19 16:00:00
.45002681310142780062180633574086272794


a
2024-12-19 17:00:00
.97880650598900392199607981380841684521


a
2024-12-19 18:00:00
.07575701266881621964163955992495478556


a
2024-12-19 19:00:00
.89284186947458030452769197367329635527


a
2024-12-19 20:00:00
.09292294849531163214283938104117282982


a
2024-12-19 21:00:00
.70235461405731196964282285394323699778


a
2024-12-19 22:00:00
.18785220468290932442103366583315927618


a
2024-12-19 23:00:00
.93635860408404301904285849466040825051


b
2024-12-19 08:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 09:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 10:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 11:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 12:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 13:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 14:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 15:00:00
.73784905889933364818896790875727033098


b
2024-12-19 16:00:00
.41769242560898808464776018211504871257


b
2024-12-19 17:00:00
.43070502409976487715182083223316452687


b
2024-12-19 18:00:00
.13393705945915339457110062298355786679


b
2024-12-19 19:00:00
.72544797021107633836594003472131801955


b
2024-12-19 20:00:00
.74336926026044610430703249831287711348


b
2024-12-19 21:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 22:00:00
0


b
2024-12-19 23:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 08:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 09:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 10:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 11:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 12:00:00
.49098968968124452450706871416259772155


c
2024-12-19 13:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 14:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 15:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 16:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 17:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 18:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 19:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 20:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 21:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 22:00:00
0


c
2024-12-19 23:00:00
0



fiddle
